# Solution :: Simplest way to setup Context Menu using Draw2d eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse, rcp

```
 Menu menu = new Menu  (editor.getSite().getShell(), SWT.POP_UP); 
 MenuItem itemA = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.PUSH); 
 itemA.setText("ItemA");  menu.setVisible(true);
```

**Then you will have enent, On click.**

```
 itemA.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {  
     public void handleEvent(Event event) {

           }    
 });
```

Comment: Is this a question ?

Comment: please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have clearly mentioned .Solution.